# magento 2 File composer.json cannot be opened

Tags: magento2, composer

I have installed an **extension** on **magento 2.0** on my local server. It works fine there.

Installed same extension on **live server** and it shows

> File "/composer.json" cannot be opened Warning!fopen(/composer.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

error when saving the form data to database.

Comment: Have you checked permissions? Are you using the absolute path of the where the file exists?

Comment: Seems rather strange that it would need access to composer.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if anybody else will come up with this issue. But incase some one does, then try checking and editing the field names.

In my case it was an issue of the field name **website**. I renamed that field and it worked fine.